How to parse aggregation query response in openseach java
{
    "took": 15,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards":
    {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits":
    {
        "total":
        {
            "value": 476,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits":
        []
    },
    "aggregations":
    {
        "agg1":
        {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 246,
            "buckets":
            [
                {
                    "key": "143567",
                    "doc_count": 20,
                    "hits":
                    {
                        "hits":
                        {
                            "total":
                            {
                                "value": 20,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 1.0,
                            "hits":
                            [
                                {
                                    "_index": "index-v14",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "2650029_e705e2b8-dbd4-4a8d-9350-fef8002af3db",
                                    "_score": 1.0,
                                    "_source":
                                    {
                                        "lastName": "abc",
                                        "firstName": "xyz",
                                    }
                                  ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "agg2":
                    {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets":
                        [
                            {
                                "key": "2024",
                                "doc_count": 12
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "2023",
                                "doc_count": 7
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "2022",
                                "doc_count": 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

I want to parse/get data under _source. I am using opensearch java library.
